# set Two text box in list view one with fix size and other with dynamic size

Tags: android

hi I am creating `ListView` with the two `TextView` in android.
The one contain the fix size and the other will occupied the remaining space of the screen.
The first which is fix size will display on the right side of the screen and other `TextView` will display data on the left of the screen.
How Can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

isn't that ok?

```
<TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="480dp" />
<TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `LinearLayout` with `horizontal` orientation, and `match_parent` width.

Put both `TextView`s in it. For the first on, use `android:layout_width` and specify the value in `dp` if you want the buttons physical size to be the same on every screen, or in `sp` if you want it to scale according to screen resolution.

For the second `TextView`, use `android:layout_width="match_parent"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView1"
              android:layout_width="70dp" //Set the dimension
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Text1" />

           <TextView
              android:id="@+id/textView2"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Text2" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:text="dfafa"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="dfafa"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: but if i want the second text box as the fix width then? how can i do this?

Comment: would fix size create problem when dimension is change according the screen?

Comment: Use Linear Layout with weight. Which solve your problem.